# Access the request url for current route in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'd like to retrieve the GET request url sent for the current route from Ember. In case it's useful, I'm interested in manipulating this url to create a separate `url` for a download that I'll pass to:

```
window.location.assign(url);
```

As a caveat, I'm not interested in retrieving the browser URL with something like:

```
this.get('router.url');
```

I'd like to retrieve the request URL sent out to my API. Is this possible with Ember? If so, any guidance on how I may pull this from the route is appreciated.

Comment: What do you actually want? The same URL that ember-data is building for you?

Comment: @Lux Yes, exactly.

Comment: You can be able to do this within [ember-data adapters](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/models/customizing-adapters/). It gaves methods to you to handle the url, such as [this method](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html#method_buildURL).

Comment: Then depending on your adapter you can call [buildUrl](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_buildURL).

Comment: @ykaragol thanks for the help.